# Calculate year-over-year growth rate of price in DolphinDB

Tags: sql, dolphindb

As shown below, I tried to calculate the year-over-year growth rate of price by joining the two tables and conducting division. But the code seems inefficient. Any efficient way to simplify the script?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See the following DolphinDB script:

```
t = table(2022.07.04T00:00:00 2021.07.04T00:00:00 2022.07.04T00:00:00 2021.07.04T00:00:00 as time, `A`A`B`B as sym, 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 as openPrice)

def groupByTime(time) {
    return substr(string(time), 5)
}
select time, sym, openPrice, ratios(openPrice) - 1 as ratios from t context by sym, groupByTime(time) as time csort time
```